# How to find last connected date of each user in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

is there a way to find out when was the each users last(date/time) connected to PostgreSQL.

my requirement is to remove the users who did not connected to PostgreSQL server for longer period.

I updated below things in the

```
postgresql.conf
```

file

```
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
```

and checked  with below query

```
select * from pg_stat_activity
```

it is giving information about current connecting users, which is not what I want.

Comment: You will want to check the logfiles - that is where the connections are being recorded.

Comment: You can use pgbadger tool to create reports from logs, and use --dbuser flag for user specific reports

Comment: This information is not stored in the database.